# Need help to make shareable partition with W7 in future for my dual-boot configuration

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

As according to my requirement right now i'd like to install ubuntu 16.04 and after 6 month or may be a year after i'll be install window7 64bit.

It's the first time I install Ubuntu. I need some advise to plan a good partition strategy.

I have 1TB Hard disk, 4GB RAM, i5, Lenovo thinkpad E-460.

I'd like to create 4 partition:

150 GB  - ubuntu and window 7 installation (dual-boot)

200 GB – work (store project files, folder, notes, workspace etc) (It’ll be share with W7 in future)

200 GB – videos etc. (It’ll be share with W7 in future)

350 GB – movies, image etc (It’ll be share with W7 in future)

one partition for ubuntu installation (dual-boot) and rest three partition should be shareable with window7 in future.

I'm not well aware the term like root, home, swap, dual-boot, Please tell me littile bit about these terms and What is the partition size should I put for swap, root and home.

```
/ (root) (Size ???)

/home (Size ???)

/swap (Size ???)
```

will root, /home shareable with W7 in future?

Please explain by image if possible.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You can't install Ubuntu and Windows 7 in the same partition. Any other non-system partition, i.e. "data" partitions like yours 2, 3 and 4, has to be NTFS.

Comment: Windows 7 is ancient and really not recommended for a Thinkpad E-460 (unless the manufacturer says otherwise *and* and provide drivers) and has an additional caveat: You want to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode and all other OSes should be installed in the same mode. The only way to install Win7 in UEFI mode is by using Microsoft's tool to make a bootable USB stick. Windows 8+ supports UEFI in a DVD (an USB is preferable anyway because it's noticeably faster).

Comment: Finally, when installing in UEFI mode the order of installation is irrelevant but it's *generally* preferable to install Windows first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to install Windows for 6-12mo+, then just install Ubuntu, **but don't do all of the partitioning foolishness**. Just create folders for work, videos, etc. Install as "erase and install". That'll wipe the disk and use all of it for Ubuntu. Later, you can repartition to make room for Windows.

Normally, it's advisable to install Windows first, then Ubuntu. If you create another NTFS partition, it can be shared between Windows and Ubuntu. That's the normal/recommended way to do a dual-boot configuration.